# Eclipse doesns't show project explorer properly

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, maven-plugin, m2eclipse

I'm using eclipse neon. I have created a maven project and create a package com.prueba.account and then I have created many packages inside.
But eclipse shows me all packages as an independent project and without the full path like in the image. Notice that checking package is inside com.prueba.account

[image]

Comment: In _Window > Preferences: Java > Appearance_ the option _Compress all package name segments, ..._ or _Abbreviate package names_ might be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Just Click on the Drop Down in Project explorer. All you need is to change Package presentation from Hierarchical to Flat. 
Hope it helps !!!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow Gary.

Then to extend on **Adyas** **Answer**:

In Eclipse there are two ways to display the package-structure.

**Hierarchical** :

[image: Hierachical]

And **Flat**:

[image: Flat]

I personally find the **Hierarchical** view way more convenient, for when you're working on a bigger project, you often get really long package names which, when in Flat view, might clutter the whole window.

But in the end, it's up to your personal taste.

The way to change between this two modes is to click on the **down arrow icon** at the top of the **Project Explorer** and under **Package Presentation** you can choose between the two.

[image]